# In GIT, data pushed to one branch is also coming in another branch of same project

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a project with multiple branches. But by mistake few of my changes are showing in both Branch A and B, while it was Pushed only to branch A.

Is this possible? Or is there any way I can find out how it got pushed to both the branches?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible

Just do

```
git reflog --date=local origin/master
```

And you'll see the pushed date and time of the commits under `origin/master` branch

Comment: do a `git fetch origin/master` before querying the reflog

Answer (score 0):

Who did the commit in branch B

- Execute "git log --format=full" to see the "Author" and the "Commiter" of the commit.
- Use the Gerrit search field to look for the suspicious commit in the branch B and try to find who is the author of the change.

Comment: I have tried that, but what I can see that this particular commit was pushed to branch A only.

there is no entry for push in branch B but still its present in here. 

Is there anyway to check when a merge was happened from branch A to branch B.

Comment: If you can not find the commit on Gerrit it means it was pushed straight to the branch (bypassing Gerrit). Have you checked who is the author and the commiter as I have suggested?